# How to show the menu of your game again in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, restart

What I am trying to do is to make a game in as3. What i did so far is that I made a game and from that .swf file loaded a menu in with the name "startScreen.swf". From that external swf file can i navigate to my storyscreen, instructionsscreen and play my game. the storyscreen and instructionsscreen are all external swf files.

What i want to do is when i press ESC, I want to unload my swf file and show my menu again. But the problem is when I press ESC my startscreen shows but when i press play game, It don't unload my startscreen again and just plays over it.

Is there a way to load all my swf files before the game starts and when I want to return to the startscreen, They just unload and load my startscreen again. Or another option is to just restart the game which is my favorite choice.

```
public var Player:MovieClip

private var leftKeyIsDown:Boolean;
private var RightKeyIsDown:Boolean;

private var aMissileArray:Array;
private var aEnemyArray:Array;

public var scoreTxt:TextField;
public var ammoTxt:TextField;
public var MenuEnd:EndGameScreen;
public var menuAgain:EndGameScreen;

private var MenuStart:mcStartGameScreen;
private var MenuStory:mcStartGameScreen;
private var MenuInstructions:mcStartGameScreen;

private var nScore:Number;
private var nAmmo:Number;
private var tEnemyTimer:Timer;

private var screens:Object = {
    "SHOW_INSTRUCTIONS":{
        "loader":new Loader(),
        "url":new URLRequest("instructionsScreen.swf")
    },
    "SHOW_STORY":{
        "loader":new Loader(),
        "url":new URLRequest("storyScreen.swf")
    },
    "START_GAME":{
        "loader":new Loader(),
        "url":new URLRequest("startScreen.swf")
    }
}
public function FirstGame() 
{
    //Create a loader object
    var startLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    //add event listener to listen for the complete event
    startLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, startLoaded);
    //load our loader object
    startLoader.load(new URLRequest("startScreen.swf"));
}

public function startLoaded(e:Event):void 
{
    MenuEnd.hideScreen();
    Player.visible = false;
    scoreTxt.visible = false;
    ammoTxt.visible = false;

    //get a reference to the loaded movieclip
    MenuStart = e.target.content as mcStartGameScreen;
    //listen for start game event
    MenuStart.addEventListener("START_GAME", playGameAgain);
    //add it to the stage
    addChild(MenuStart);

    //get a reference to the loaded movieclip
    MenuStory = e.target.content as mcStartGameScreen;
    //listen for start game event
    MenuStory.addEventListener("SHOW_STORY", storyGameScreen);
    //add it to the stage
    addChild(MenuStory);

    //get a reference to the loaded movieclip
    MenuInstructions = e.target.content as mcStartGameScreen;
    //listen for start game event
    MenuInstructions.addEventListener("SHOW_INSTRUCTIONS", instructionsGameScreen);
    //add it to the stage
    addChild(MenuInstructions);
}

private function instructionsGameScreen(e:Event):void 
{
    var instructionsLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("instructionsScreen.swf");
    instructionsLoader.load(url);
    addChild(instructionsLoader);

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, esc);
}

private function storyGameScreen(e:Event):void 
{
    var storyLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("storyScreen.swf");
    storyLoader.load(url);
    addChild(storyLoader);

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, esc);
}

private function esc(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if (e.keyCode == 27) 
    {
        //fscommand("quit");

        //(new URLRequest(stage.loaderInfo.url), "FirstGame.swf");

    }
}

private function playGameAgain(e:Event):void 
{

    //initialize variables
    aMissileArray = new Array();
    aEnemyArray = new Array();
    nScore = 0;
    nAmmo = 20;
    Player.x = 262,95
    Player.y = 323,30

    Player.visible = true;
    scoreTxt.visible = true;
    ammoTxt.visible = true;

    MenuStart.hideScreen();


    MenuEnd.addEventListener("PLAY_AGAIN", playGameAgain);
    MenuEnd.hideScreen();

    updateScoreText();
    updateAmmoText();

    //trace("First Game Loaded");
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop)

    //creat an timer object
    tEnemyTimer = new Timer(1000)
    //listen for the timer ticks/intervals
    tEnemyTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addEnemy)
    //start our timer
    tEnemyTimer.start();

}
```

You can see by the storyscreen when you press ESC. There is nothing. There I want to restart or load my startscreen and unload the other swf files.

Comment: You do not "unload" screens, you add or remove them fromt he display list via `addChild()` and `removeChild()` calls. So, you have to load all the screens of yours once (!), save them to variables, then `addChild(startScreen);`, add listeners to it, and `removeChild(startScreen)` when you want to show a different screen, be it play the game or story or whatever.

Comment: How do I unload these screens at once? Is it like i tried 

"private var screens:Object"
Or how else?